# if statement inside an Angularjs object depends on HTML select option

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to put if condition in object to capture a certain 2 HTML select option, and the angular will post to the data base a certain values based on the selection of the user

HTML

```
<tr>
                <td>End Of Contract By</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Age">Age</option>
                        <option ng-model="NYears">Number Of Years in Service</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Num_EndWork">
                    <select>
                        <option ng-model="Months">Months</option>
                        <option ng-model="Years">Years</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Controller

```
var Contract = { Code: $scope.selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code, Latin: $scope.selectedMember.Latin.L_Desc, Local: $scope.selectedMember.Local.A_Desc, Nend: $scope.selectedMember.Num_EndWork, Tend: $scope.Type_EndWork, hd: $scope.selectedMember.Hours_Day, dw: $scope.selectedMember.Days_Week }

    if (!$scope.selectedMember.sys_key ) {
        crudService.post(Contract).then(function (response) {
            $scope.Contract = (res.data)
            $scope.selectedMember = {};
            loadrecords();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
    }
}
```

i want if the user select 1st option in select option and 1st in second select option , insert to database value 1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First change your code. Like below. Refer this links how to use select tag options.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

```
<select ng-model="ageYear">
           <option value="Age">Age</option>
          <option value="NYears">Number Of Years in Service</option>
   </select>
    </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>Number</td>
                <td>
       <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Please enter numbers only" size="10" maxlength="2" ng-model="selectedMember.Num_EndWork">
     <select ng-model="typeOftime">
         <option value="Months">Months</option>
           <option value="Years">Years</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option should not have ng-model , only select should have

```
 <select ng-model="selectedContract">
   <option>Age</option>
   <option>Number Of Years in Service</option>
 </select>

 <select ng-model="selectedNumber">
   <option value="Months">Months</option>
   <option value="Years">Years</option>
 </select>
```

Then inside your controller you can just check and insert 1 if the condition matches

```
if($scope.selectedContract =='Age' && $scope.selectedNumber =='Months'){

}
```